# how to place the button in the the menu bar and the label immediately to the left of the button

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a menu bar which is the header for my web application i have taken a label to bind the username who is getting logged in and a button logout the problem is my label and the button should be in the menu bar only though they are in the menu but the button logout can be clearly seen that it is getting seperated from menu i need to place button to the right and the label to the left of the button.How can i do this.

Below is my css code

```
/*---Reset----*/

body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,textarea,p,block
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
/*body*/
body {
    background-color:rgb(237,237,237);
    font-family:"Arial",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
/*Page*/
.wrapper {
    width:1430px;
    margin:auto;
}
/*Home Page*/
.content {
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgb(254,254,254);
    border:1px solid rgb(224,224,224);
    border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    min-height:600px;
}
/*Menu*/
.menu {
    background-color: rgb(10,110,178);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    color: rgb(243,243,243);
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.navigation_first_item {
    border-left: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.navitem_s {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(10,85,125);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(67,153,200);
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgb(14,79,114);
}
.menu ul {
}
.menu ul li {
        float:left;
        display:block;
        list-style:none;
        border-right:1px solid rgb(10,85,125);
        border-left:1px solid rgb(67,153,200);

}
.menu ul li.navigation_first_item:hover {
            border-radius:5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
.menu ul li a {
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:8px 20px;
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
    text-decoration:none;
    }
.menu ul li:hover {
        background-color: rgb(14,79,114);
        border-right: 1px solid rgb(14,89,130);

}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
/*Footer*/
.footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(10,110,178);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
    .footer h2 {
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct. I did exactly as you asked and will be willing to help you again in the future. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For css code you could do

```
*
{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

instead of

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,textarea,p,block
{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Also, it seems like you are asking about how to set the placement of your radio buttons. Create an id or class (which you seem to have done) and use the css to place before the labels.

I am a bit confused on your question and what you are asking though.

Update:

```
     <div style="float: left;text-align:right; width: 45%;"> <asp:Button ID="Logout" runat="server" OnClick="Logout_Click" Text="Logout" Height="41px" Width="60px" style="font-weight:bold;background-color:rgb(10,110,178);flo‌​at:right;color:white‌​"/><li id="Logout" runat="server"><a href="logout.aspx" id="Rpf" runat="server">Logout</li> </div>
```

Comment: @xyz Please mark my answer as correct, as it is exactly what you asked for. Much appreciated- gmonz

Comment: please replace all the html code with this code   <div style="float: left;text-align:right; width: 45%;"> 
                    <asp:Button ID="Logout" runat="server" OnClick="Logout_Click" Text="Logout" Height="41px" Width="60px" style="font-weight:bold;background-color:rgb(10,110,178);float:right;color:white"/><li id="Logout" runat="server"><a href="logout.aspx" id="Rpf" runat="server">Logout</li> 
                         </div> as this is enough for our solution then i will mark it as ans for sure

Comment: okay @xyz it has been updated with what you requested. Please mark as answer. Thank you.

Comment: @xyz Please mark my answer as correct. I did exactly as you asked and will be willing to help you again in the future. Thank you.